# How do I find out the number of filetypes in my SharePoint 2013 farm?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a Large SharePoint 2013 farm and i need to know if there is any way i can see how many files of each type there is in the farm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you could use below PowerShell get all files of document content type.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") > $null

function global:Get-SPSite($url){
    return new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
}
 
Function GetFiles($Folder)
{
    foreach ($File in $Folder.Files | Where-Object {$_.Name -match ".doc"} )
    {
     #Write data to CSV File
     "$($Folder.ParentWeb.Site.RootWeb.Title)" +"`t"+ "$($Folder.ParentWeb.Title)" +"`t" + "$($Folder.ParentWeb.URL+"/")$($File.URL)" +"`t" + "$($File.TimeLastModified)" >> C:\Templates.csv
    }
 
    foreach ($SubFolder in $Folder.SubFolders)
    {
        #Call the function recursively
        GetFiles $SubFolder
    }
}
  
"Site Collection `t Site `t Form Template `t Last Modified" > C:\Templates.csv
 
$WebAppURL= "web application URL"
$SiteColletion = Get-SPSite($WebAppURL)
$WebApp = $SiteColletion.WebApplication
      
    foreach ($site in $WebApp.Sites)
    { 
    
       foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
        {
              write-host "scanning site" $web.title "@" $web.URL
                         
              GetFiles($Web.RootFolder)
               
         $web.dispose()
        }
  
        $site.Dispose()
    }
Write-host  "Report Generated: C:\Templates.csv" -foregroundcolor green
```